# AJAX call to ruby script "Method Not Implemented"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, apache

(First off, I'm not using Ruby on Rails here)

I have an jQuery.ajax call to a ruby script -

```
ajaxCall = function() {

    $.ajax({
            url: "/controllers/main.rb",
            context: document.body,
            type: "text",
            success: function(data){

                    alert("yep")

            }

    });

}
```

Bit it fails with this error -

```
Method Not Implemented
SCRIPT to /controllers/main.rb not supported.
Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.168.2.2 Port 80
```

I get a similar error if I change the 'type' to anything else, ie 'script'.

The Ruby script is nothing special, it just passes back some text (this is just a test I'm trying). But it doesn't seem to even get far enough to attempt running it.

```
@var = "This worked"
render :text => "This worked and #{@var}"
```

I have a suspicion that this might be some Apache configuration needed? I'm not sure, have been searching for info but can't find anything.

Comment: Ok, I fixed it be removing this line completely:

    type:"text"

Looks like it wouldn't run if that parameter was defined.

I had tried that already, but there was also a typo in my Ruby script that was obsuring the test (I used 'return' instead of 'render').

Comment: It looks like main.rb is a rails controller and you're trying to get apache to serve it as a cgi script. Have you thought that through?